# Trouble outputting powershell result to text file

Tags: powershell

I have this in a powershell script

```
Get-Content -Path list1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 14)
} | Out-File -FilePath list2.txt
```

but it dosent save the result to the file.

If i remove `| Out-File -FilePath list2.txt` it successfully outputs to the powershell window.

plz help ty

Comment: You should get errors when a string in the input file is shorter than 14.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try this, Hope it helps

```
Get-Content -Path list1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 14)
} >> result.txt
```

I tried using the script that you have posted here. **IT WORKS !!**

```
 Get-Content -Path list1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 14)
} | Out-File -FilePath list2.txt
```

Comment: There is no (substantial) functional difference between these two commands (`>>` should be `>`), and the 2nd command is by definition identical with the one in the question. The code as posted in the question always worked as expected (except for the potential to report errors for lines with fewer than 14 characters). Therefore, there is no question here, and thus no need for an answer - this question and answer pair will at best be _confusing_ to future readers.